# running xctest from command line

Tags: xctest

I want to create logic tests for my library and run them on iOS device. I know that we can only run them on simulator. But I have seen that I can run the default test on iOS device. Here is the setup.

1. Create new iOS 7.0 app (single view application, nothing fancy) using xcode 5.
2. This will create default test which fails with message failed - No implementation for "-[MyAppTests testExample] when you try to run it.
3. I am able to run this test both on simulator and device using xcode with same output.

Does that mean I can run XCTests on device also?

Also when I try to run the same test using command line it gives me error saying the scheme is not testable. The how come Xcode is able to run it? Here is the command line that I execute to run on device.

`xcodebuild test -scheme MyApp  -configuration Debug -destination name=TestIPhone`

and am seeing following message

`2014-03-14 16:04:12.423 xcodebuild[620:1207] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-3582/Framework/Classes/Model/Execution/RunContext/IDEScheme.m:1290
Details:  Scheme <IDEScheme:0x7ff6abc8d2b0:'MyAppTests'> was asked to test, but it is not testable and shouldn't have allowed this action.
Object:   <IDEScheme: 0x7ff6abc8d2b0>
Method:   -testOperationWithExecutionContext:buildIfNeeded:onlyBuild:destination:overridingProperties:overridingTestingSpecifiers:buildLog:overridingBuildConfiguration:restorePersistedBuildResults:invocationRecord:name:title:error:actionCallbackBlock:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff6abc0e5d0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project MyAppTests with scheme MyAppTests.
    Reason: Scheme "MyAppTests" is not testable.`

Any insight would be helpful. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved with Xcode5.1 update.